Apache kafka in Kraft mode using 3 node cluster set up for Docker-compose iam getting some error how can i resove it
version: '3'

services:
  broker-1:
    image: apache/kafka:latest
    container_name: broker-1
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://13.201.80.230:9092,CONTROLLER://13.201.80.230:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://13.201.80.230:9092
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@13.201.80.230:9093,2@13.201.101.151:9093,3@13.235.76.195:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 2
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --bootstrap-server 13.201.80.230:9092 > /dev/null 2>&1",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

This is my docker-compose file I was to set up 3 node cluster. Iam getting this ERROR Unable to start acceptor for ListenerName(CONTROLLER) (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor) org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 13.201.80.230:9093: Address not available."
see Iam using this type also KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://13.201.80.230:9092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093, but I am getting Kafka broker's attempt to maintain connections with multiple nodes, with repeated disconnections occurring between nodes (node 2 and node 3).

What do you hope to achieve by running more than one controller? Why do you need to use IP addresses?

Iam using EC2  instances that's why i mention IP's. Iam always getting this error only"ERROR Unable to start acceptor for ListenerName(CONTROLLER) (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor) org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 13.201.80.230:9093: Address not available."

I recommend you switch to Serverless MSK rather than EC2. Much less to manage and cheaper, scalable, more secure, etc. Docker Compose isn't how you run a cluster in EC2

ok, why iam getting this error

It's a network error. We don't have access to your network to troubleshoot for you. My point was that Docker Compose isn't what you'd use in Production
